# java - Quick Sort - ArrayList - is not working

Tags: java

I am having trouble finding a bug in this sorting algorithm. When I pass an array to the sort method, say 5,6,4,7,1, I get the same array as result. I've been going through code but I cannot find where it is going wrong. Disregard SortThread task, it's an argument that will update the progress bar, but I am not using it right now.

```
class QuickSort extends Sort {

@Override
ArrayList<Integer> sort(ArrayList<Integer> array, SortThread task) {

    if (array.size() <= 1) {
        return array;
    }

    int middle = (int) Math.ceil((double) array.size() / 2);
    int pivot = array.get(middle);

    ArrayList<Integer> less = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> greater = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (array.get(i) <= pivot) {
            if (i == middle) {
                continue;
            }
            less.add(array.get(i));
        } else {
            greater.add(array.get(i));
        }
    }

    return concatenate(sort(less, task), pivot, sort(greater, task));
}

private ArrayList<Integer> concatenate(ArrayList<Integer> less, int pivot, ArrayList<Integer> greater) {

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < less.size(); i++) {
        list.add(less.get(i));
    }

    list.add(pivot);

    for (int i = 0; i < greater.size(); i++) {
        list.add(greater.get(i));
    }

    return list;
}
```

}

Comment: Just to be sure : you do this as a game/exercise ? You're not planning to really use such an algorithm full of ArrayList creations and you're aware that java already has sort functions ?

Comment: TIP: Please debug line by line using debugger, then definitively you will get a catch where problem is occurring. This applies for all the code you develop. Good debugging using debugger a skill must for every developer :)

Comment: @dystroy yes this is an exercise, I am aware there are methods in java that do so.

Comment: Good first step in debugging; get print outs at different steps of the execution. See if little bits of code do what they are supposed to do. Do you have unit tests for your methods?

Comment: Can you show the code where you call (initially) the sort method?

Comment: @posdef I am using a state pattern, when you select a radio button you change the state and get desired sorting algorithm. you input the length of array and the program randoms it, then it prints randomized array, it sorts it, and then it prints again.

Comment: Just tried your algorithms, and it sorted just fine... (using Java 1.6) Are you sure you are actually calling that algorithm, and not e.g. the super class?

Comment: I also tested it. And it works!

Comment: @tobias_k I am, sort is initially Sort sort = new BubbleSort(); but when I click on quick sort radio button> sort= new QuickSort(); then when i hit run button it-s supposed to do sort.sort(array, task); so I think it is good, no idea why it isn-t working.

Comment: Okay, just a sanity check: This isn't doing an in place sort.  It returns a new sorted array, rather than sorting the old one in place.  You need to call it like `array = sort.sort(array, task);`  Is that what you are doing?

Comment: Yea that fixed it, thank you. I have no idea how it actually worked all this time with other sorts.

Comment: I would suppose your other sorts ARE in-place sorts.  Bubblesort, which you mentioned, is typically implemented as an in-place sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The others have it right that you are probably printing the original as your code works fine.

You could try this instead, which will sort it in-situ, thus having less unexpected behaviour and being slightly more efficient. All I have done is made `concatenate` take a new parameter which is where it should put its results.

BTW: I would suggest you pull out the `if (i == middle) { continue; }` to before you compare, this would also be slightly more efficient.

```
static class QuickSort {

  public static ArrayList<Integer> sort(ArrayList<Integer> array) {

    if (array.size() <= 1) {
      return array;
    }

    int middle = (int) Math.ceil((double) array.size() / 2);
    int pivot = array.get(middle);

    ArrayList<Integer> less = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> greater = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
      if (array.get(i) <= pivot) {
        if (i == middle) {
          continue;
        }
        less.add(array.get(i));
      } else {
        greater.add(array.get(i));
      }
    }

    return concatenate(sort(less), pivot, sort(greater), array);
  }

  private static ArrayList<Integer> concatenate(ArrayList<Integer> less, int pivot, ArrayList<Integer> greater, ArrayList<Integer> list) {

    list.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < less.size(); i++) {
      list.add(less.get(i));
    }

    list.add(pivot);

    for (int i = 0; i < greater.size(); i++) {
      list.add(greater.get(i));
    }

    return list;
  }
}
```

you could further improve concatenate to:

```
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(less);
    list.add(pivot);
    list.addAll(greater);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing any actual sorting.  You are just putting everything into smaller lists, then putting them back into a larger list.  You need some comparisons in there.

Look at your concatenate method.  Your are just putting the less list back into the less list.  You need to compare the value to the pivot to determine where that value should go.

EDIT:  My initial thought was wrong. I tested your code and it worked.

I'm guessing you are printing out the the array you passed in?  Note that the actual array you pass into your sort function is not sorted.  Only the one returned.

Comment: [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is a divide and conquer algorithm, which works by dividing the set into recursively smaller lists on either side of a pivot, and then merges them back together. This appears to be what their implementation is doing, to me.

Comment: Yes, it is merging them back together, but in the exact same order.

Comment: No, they are being split into the array less, where array.get(i) <= pivot and greater, where array.get(i) > pivot.  Then merged back in in the order less + pivot + greater, so, ignoring recursion, it can be guaranteed everything is correctly positioned with regards to pivot, although the subarrays less and greater may be out of order (the recursion takes care of that).

Comment: Yeah, I see that now.  I'm guessing that the bug is in the assignment of the return value.

Answer (score -1):

array.get(i) returns an Integer, you need to extract the wrapped int, otherwise you are comparing the pointers.